# Number Sequence (hope it is not too hard)

Tags: number-sequence

### Complete this number sequence

1, __ , 2 , 6, 120, 40320, 6227020800 , __ , 2.952328e+38, __ , __ , __

Can you do it?

Comment: Pointing out that this sequence is on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A060001), so it makes it rather easy.

Comment: Even if it weren't, it's not too hard to notice one thing all the numbers have in common, which again leads pretty directly to a solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are

> factorials of fibonacci numbers

So the missing numbers are

> 1!, **1!**, 2!, 3!, 5!, 8!, 13!, **21!**, 34!, **55!**, **89!**, **144!**,
>  these are rather large numbers, 5.1x10^19, 1.3x10^73, 1.7x10^136, 5.6x10^249